# iMac G5 running IBM PPC. Processor

Tags: intel, powerpc

Is there a way to emulate or VM the ppc processor to run intel instruction set such that the g5 iMac can run above 
OS X 10.05.08 ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is not really appropriate here, this is a programming site not a processor architecture/operating system one. To be honest I think you will be out of luck with this requirement - a quick google doesn't show anything in this space, and I am not honestly sure what the use case would be for such a thing, even if the architectures were not so different as to make it a vast technology challenge.

Comment: You can run an x86 emulator like QEMU on any hardware, but it will be so slow you'd probably rather just use an old version of OS X.  There's no *efficient* way.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to this site. I am trying to fit in. Thanks Pete on the QEMU suggestion. Yes anything to interface is very slow .